# How to get dll names of .Net framework assembly dependencies from unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, unmanaged

I'm trying to get a list of assembly dependencies of .net exe or dll from c++ programm. For now my target platform is Windows 10 with .Net greater v4. I found only a few topics about this problem and after all I created test program that shows assembly names from .net pe file. This sample demonstrates how to get assembly names from unmanaged c++ code.

```
CComPtr<ICLRMetaHost> pMetaHost;
CComPtr<ICLRRuntimeInfo> pRuntime;
CComPtr<IMetaDataDispenser> pDisp;
CComPtr<IMetaDataAssemblyImport> pAssImport;

HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost,IID_ICLRMetaHost,(void **)&pMetaHost);

wchar_t fileVersion[MAX_PATH] = {};
DWORD dwBuffer = MAX_PATH;
hr = pMetaHost->GetVersionFromFile(file.c_str(),fileVersion,&dwBuffer);

hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(fileVersion,IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo,(void **)&pRuntime);

hr = pRuntime->GetInterface(CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser,IID_IMetaDataDispenser,(void **)&pDisp);

hr = pDisp->OpenScope(file.c_str(), ofRead, IID_IMetaDataAssemblyImport, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown **>(&pAssImport));

mdAssemblyRef  Files[50] = { 0 };
ULONG numTokensOut = 0;
ULONG numTokensIn = 50;
HCORENUM hCoreEnum = NULL;

hr = pAssImport->EnumAssemblyRefs(&hCoreEnum, Files, numTokensIn, &numTokensOut);

for (ULONG j = 0; j < numTokensOut; ++j) {
    wchar_t publicKey[MAX_PATH];
    ULONG ulPublicKeyLen;
    wchar_t simpleName[MAX_PATH];
    ULONG ulSimpleName;
    ASSEMBLYMETADATA assmd{};
    wchar_t hash[MAX_PATH];
    ULONG ulHash = MAX_PATH;
    DWORD dwAssemblyRefFlags;

    hr = pAssImport->GetAssemblyRefProps(Files[j], (const void**)&publicKey, &ulPublicKeyLen, simpleName, MAX_PATH, &ulSimpleName, &assmd, (const void**)&hash, &ulHash,&dwAssemblyRefFlags);
}
if (hCoreEnum)
    pAssImport->CloseEnum(hCoreEnum);
```

And now i need to bind assembly to specific dll file. I know, that this files is in C:\Windows\Assembly directory, but in my OS there is files for GAC, .Net 2 and .Net 4 with separate folders for x32 and x64 files.

I thought that IMetaDataAssemblyImport::FindAssembliesByName help me choose specific file, but i had a problem with this method. In documentation there is a remark for this method:

> you must call CoInitializeEE (passing COINITEE_DEFAULT) before calling FindAssembliesByName

This call is deprecated and i used ICLRRuntimeHost::Start to start CLR

```
CComPtr<ICLRRuntimeHost> pRuntimeHost;    
hr = pRuntime->GetInterface(CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_ICorRuntimeHost, (LPVOID *)&pRuntimeHost);

hr = pRuntimeHost->Start();
```

And now I get an exception during Start method

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> ThreadStore::s_pThreadStore was nullptr.

Is my method correct to do this? Or maybe there is a easier method? I think starting CLR is not a best way, but I don't know how I can avoid it. Maybe I can use version of .Net from assembly and do search in assembly directory, but in this case it is hard to solve what version of dll's I must use (x32 or x64).

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem and i don't found solution. In general there are two system places with assemblies, they produce 2 or 3 versions of {name}.ni.dll in other folders and every dll has it's own dependencies. I searched information in DotNetPeLib and asked questions from it's author and rejected this idea.

Answer (score 0):

my path for extracting dependencies from an application was this:

1. Find the name of the application (app.dll, app.exe)
2. Extract **IMetaDataAssemblyImport** from **corProfiler->GetModuleMetaData(...)**
3. Extract the name of the current assembly with **corProfiler->GetModuleInfo2Check(..)**
4. Check if the name of the current assembly has the name of the application
5. If it does, use **IMetaDataAssemblyImport** to extract assemblyRefs with **EnumAssemblyRefs(...)**
6. Iterate through the list of refs you got from step 5 and use **IMetaDataAssemblyImport** and **GetAssemblyRefProps(...)** to read assembly info

The name returned will be the dependency name and you can extract the version from **ASSEMBLYMETADATA** returned from **GetAssemblyRefProps(...)** (ASSEMBLYMETADATA.usMajorVersion and ASSEMBLYMETADATA.usMinorVersion).

Hope this helps!